# Configuring the validator provided to @Valid for message interpolation

Tags: jax-rs, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

I'm using the hibernate validator:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
  <version>5.1.2.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

In my unit test, it works just fine using it this way:

```java
  private static Validator validator;

  validator = ValidatorProvider.getInstance().getValidator();
```

with the validator being configured for message interpolation:

```java
public class ValidatorProvider {

    static ValidatorProvider INSTANCE;
    Validator validator;

    private ValidatorProvider() {
        CustomMessageInterpolator messageInterpolator = new CustomMessageInterpolator();
        ValidatorFactory validatorFactory
                = Validation.byProvider(HibernateValidator.class).configure()
                .messageInterpolator(messageInterpolator).buildValidatorFactory();
        validator = validatorFactory.getValidator();
    }

    public static ValidatorProvider getInstance() {
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            INSTANCE = new ValidatorProvider();
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    public Validator getValidator() {
        return validator;
    }
}
```

The above singleton is not being used by the integration tests.

Now, in my REST controller, I only have the @Valid annotation:

```java
@Valid Answer answer
```

For now, the following message:

```
javax.validation.constraints.Pattern.message=The "{0}" value must match "{regexp}".
```

is not interpolated when used in the integration test.

How can I tell the above `@Valid` annotation that it should use my configured validator ?

Answer (score 1):

Which REST framework are you using? Depending on the specific implementation it may be possible to inject a `ValidatorFactory` in one way or another.

The simplest though would be to not bootstrap the validator yourself, but rather let the REST framework do it, applying the configuration from [META-INF/validation.xml](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#chapter-xml-configuration) (the "default validator factory"). You can set message interpolators and many other things in that XML file and constraint mapping files which it may include.

Comment: I'm using rest-assured from jayway

Comment: You'd know how to do that in Java or annotations ?

Comment: These are integration tests, and I'm not bootstrapping any validator myself. The above singleton is not being used. It's just a configuration example. I still think there should be a way to configure a validator even if it is provided by the framework. Using the @Valid annotation does provide the validator and it works almost the way I want it to. Almost, because I'd like it to interpolate the messages.

Comment: You might set a break point in the `ValidatorFactoryImpl` constructor to see from where it is invoked and whether you may inject your own configured instance there.